# How make a update using java netbeans and sqlservel

Tags: java, netbeans, sql-update, crud

I want to make a CRUD in netbeans and sqlserver,I have already learnt how make the inserts and deletes but I haven't abled to solve the update.Help me please.

These are my codes:
name database abarrotes, table producto.

Method update:

```
public void ModificarProducto (Producto c){

            try{
             con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abarrotes", "root", "123");
            String sentencia = "UPDATE producto SET Nombre_Producto= ?, Marca_Producto = ?, Presentacion_Producto=?, Precio_Producto=?, Punto_de_Reorden = ?, Existencia = ? where Id_Producto=?;";
        PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sentencia);

        pstm.setInt(1, c.getId_Producto());
        pstm.setString(2, c.getNombre_Producto());
        pstm.setString(3, c.getMarca_Producto());
        pstm.setString(4, c.getPresentacion_Producto());
        pstm.setFloat(5, c.getPrecio_Producto());
        pstm.setInt(6, c.getPunto_de_Reorden());
        pstm.setInt(7, c.getExistencia());
        pstm.execute();
        pstm.close();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

The frame's boton

```
OperacionesProducto basedatos = new  OperacionesProducto();

 private void Btn_InsertarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        Producto prod = new Producto();

        prod.setId_Producto(Integer.parseInt(Id_Producto.getText()));
        prod.setNombre_Producto(Nombre_Producto.getText());
        prod.setMarca_Producto(Marca_Producto.getText());
        prod.setPresentacion_Producto(Presentacion_Producto.getText());
        prod.setPrecio_Producto(Float.parseFloat(Precio_Producto.getText()));
        prod.setPunto_de_Reorden(Integer.parseInt(Punto_de_Reorden.getText()));
        prod.setExistencia(Integer.parseInt(Existencia.getText()));

        basedatos.InsertarProducto(prod);

    }
```

DOESN'T MARK ANY ERROR BUT THE DATABASE DOESN'T CHANGE

HELP ME PLEASE :).

Comment: **a.)** don't use `pstm.execute();` use `pstm.executeUpdate()`. **b.)** please show us where you call `ModificarProducto (Producto c)` , **c.)** also test for the number of updates. `int n = pstm.executeUpdate();` If `n` is `0` means :   **The statement executed was an update statement that affected zero rows.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the ? in the query string doesn't match the indexes of the set commands. I think the first needs to be last and everything else moved up one to make all the names match. Change to:

```
    String sentencia = "UPDATE producto SET "
            + "Nombre_Producto= ?, "
            + "Marca_Producto = ?, "
            + "Presentacion_Producto=?, "
            + "Precio_Producto=?, "
            + "Punto_de_Reorden = ?, "
            + "Existencia = ? "
            + "where Id_Producto=?;";

    PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sentencia);

    pstm.setString(1, c.getNombre_Producto());
    pstm.setString(2, c.getMarca_Producto());
    pstm.setString(3, c.getPresentacion_Producto());
    pstm.setFloat(4, c.getPrecio_Producto());
    pstm.setInt(5, c.getPunto_de_Reorden());
    pstm.setInt(6, c.getExistencia());
    pstm.setInt(7, c.getId_Producto());
```

Comment: there I had the error at the "pstm" I only changed the (Id_Producto) to possition 7 and my project doesn't mark errors anymore. THANK YOU!!! :)!!!!!!!!